Holonomy along a circle of constant latitude and Gaussian curvature
I ran into a problem that I cannot reconcile by myself when studying the relation between holonomy and Gaussian curvature. In particular, let $S$ be a sphere of radius $1$ parametrized as usual:
$$\psi (\theta, \phi) = (\sin\phi \cos\theta, \sin\phi\sin\theta, \cos\phi)$$
I am able to calculate the holonomy along a circle of constant latitude, say $\phi$, to be $\int_0^{2\pi}\cos\phi d\theta = 2\pi \cos\phi$.
However, I also saw that the holonomy along a closed curve is equal to the surface integral of Gaussian curvature on the region enclosed by the curve. In this particular case, this is equal to
$$\iint_{D} K dA = \iint_{D} dA$$
since $K=1$. Now here comes my first question: which region should I choose? It seems like the polar cap and the rest of the sphere are both regions enclosed by the circle. If I choose $D$ as the polar cap, then the area is $2\pi(1-\cos\phi)$, while choosing the rest region gives $2\pi(1+\cos\phi)$, neither gives the answer $2\pi \cos\phi$.
I have also seen the Gaussian curvature being defined as
$$K=\lim_{r\rightarrow 0}\frac{\textsf{Holonomy along a curve}}{\textsf{Area of the enclosed region}}$$
where $r$ is understood as the "size" of the curve. This implies that when the region is getting closer to 0, the holonomy should also be close to 0 for this definition to be meaningful. However in our specific example, the holonomy of a circle close the pole is close to $2\pi$. My guess is that there is some sort of "singularity" at the poles, but I am not able to specify what exactly. Any help is greatly appreciated.

The holonomy is actually $-2\pi\cos\phi$, and the angle the vector turns is $2\pi(1-\cos\phi)$. The holonomy changes sign if you go backwards on the curve, and you need to apply usual orientation rules for the boundary of a region (as you do to apply Green's Theorem).
See the discussion on pp. 80-83 of my differential geometry text. In particular, see Example 2 on pp. 82-83.

Prof. Shifrin, thank you for your reply ! I actually read your notes before asking the questions. The computation of the holonomy is not the main issue, what I don't understand is its relation with the Gaussian curvature. Are you saying that when defining the Gaussian curvature, we should be looking at "the angle the vector turns" instead of "holonomy"? After asking the question I did a calculation to find the holonomy along a circle on the flat plane, and it's $2\pi$, but the turned angle is actually 0.

Holonomy is actually (officially) defined mod $2\pi$. How are you coming up with $2\pi$ in the flat plane? But, yes, as Corollary 1.4 in section 1 of chapter 3 indicates, I want to look at angle turned.
